# Sass extend class from module

Tags: sass

With the new module system in sass (with @use instead of @import) how can i define a class in one file and the use it in another file with @extend ?

File **colors.scss**

```
 .element {
   background-color: blue;
 }
```

main file

```
@use "./colors.scss" as colors;
body {
  @extend .element;
}
```

This gives the following error:

> "body" failed to @extend ".element".
>   The selector ".element" was not found.
>   Use "@extend .element !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.

Example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tufq7f?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

How can I tell sass to get it from **colors.scss**?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are a few different problems here. The first is that the stacblitz example is using an old version of sass witch does not have module support. The other is that there is no way to specify from witch sass module to extend a css class from. The correct solution is what I wrote in the question:

`@extend .element;`

Comment: I saw your question on Github as well. It still does not work for me when I @use from another file. What exactly did you change? I'm doing the exact same thing as you and it's not working.

Comment: Does not work on stackblitz even with the correct code. Found several other issues as well and decided to wait with the change to sass modules until it's more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
@use "./colors.scss" as colors;
body {
  @extend colors.element;
}
```

(Modules are imported as a namespace, so you have to 'use' the 'module' by it's name)
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace