# SASS @extend a class imported with @use

Tags: sass

I reproduced this is issue in codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hertz-j0pg1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I'm just trying to extend a class from inside another file.

```
// common.scss:
.common_class_to_import {
    text-align: right
}
```

File 2:

```
// not_common.scss
@use "./common.scss";

.not_common {
  @extend .common_class_to_import
}
```

Error: Error: ".not_common" failed to @extend ".common_class_to_import".
       The selector ".common_class_to_import" was not found.

Another answer here: [Sass extend class from module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630514/sass-extend-class-from-module/59652092#comment106781345_59652092)  does not really answer the question at all, and suggests that it could be caused by an older version of SASS. I am using Sass 3.7.4, which should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use sass modules in create-react-app with the new @use syntax but receiving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343131/trying-to-use-sass-modules-in-create-react-app-with-the-new-use-syntax-but-rece)

Comment: Yep! Didn't see that answer, thanks! I will post an answer in a few hours unless youd like to

Comment: An answer is not necessary as this question is marked as duplicate. =)